# [__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode5

I am creating an app the scans barcodes and retrieves information from a web service.

I have a web service set up that is returning values in JSON format. When logging all values within the JSON everything works fine. The problem is when trying to log single values. The app crashes and I see  this:

- Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170224f40' *

Doing plenty of research I have come across a few questions here that resemble the same problem I am encountering. Some are of great help sending me in the proper direction. I still cannot find a solution to why this is happening though.

Here is the code where the app is crashing:

```
//NSDisctionary
res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

for(id key in res) {

    id value = [res objectForKey:key];

    NSString *keyAsString = (NSString *)key;
    NSString *valueAsString = (NSString *)value;

    NSLog(@"key: %@", keyAsString);
    NSLog(@"value: %@", valueAsString);
}

//NSMutableArray
results = [res objectForKey:@"error"];

//result is a dictionary
for (result in results) {

    message = [result objectForKey:@"message"];

    NSLog(@"Code Above: %@", message);

}
```

The app crashes in the second for loop here:

```
message = [result objectForKey:@"message"];
```

This is what my JSON looks like:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 1,
        "message": "No UPC Code for this scan"
    },
    "data": null
}
```

Is anyone able to see where I am going wrong here? A hint in the right direction would be truly appreciated.

Thanks so much.

Comment: What's the value of `res` before you get to your for loop? Your JSON will translate to nested NSCFDictionaries (a class cluster of NSDictionary), and thus you won't be able to cast it to a string.

Comment: The value of res is the data I receive from my web service. 

My apologies if this doesn't answer your question. I am not too sure what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, I meant put a break point there and inspect it - make sure what you see is the data you expect. Then you'll need to grab another dictionary out with objectForKey (which would return another NSDictionary)

Comment: NSLog your "dictionaries" -- one of them is really an NSString.

Comment: Seriously?  Literally every link in the related section (except for a few) is the same question as this one...

Comment: res has two objects but the value of the objects is none. The value of res is 0x0000000170462d40 @remus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//NSMutableArray
results = [res objectForKey:@"error"];

//result is a dictionary
for (result in results) {

    message = [result objectForKey:@"message"];

    NSLog(@"Code Above: %@", message);

}
```

When you fast enumerate a dictionary, you're fast enumerating its *keys*. Thus, `result` is a key within `results`. And so `[result objectForKey:@"message"]` is trying to treat a string like a dictionary.

You probably meant to type `[[results objectForKey:result] objectForKey:@"message"]` instead. Though I'd write it as `results[result][@"message"]` instead.

Also, why is `results` defined as a mutable array? Based on the JSON, it's a dictionary. The compiler can't really know that, so it trusts you that it's an array, which means the `NSArray` type is checked for an `objectForKey:` method at compile time. `results` should be a dictionary.

See also:

- developer.apple.com, [Fast Enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000135-SW1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Steven.

When changing result to results I receive the error "No Visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'objectForKey'".

Comment: Why is results defined as an array? Based on the JSON, it's a dictionary. The compiler can't really know that, so it trusts you that it's an array, which causes this compiler error. Fix the type to dictionary and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
results = [res objectForKey:@"error"]; // results is NSDictionary with keys "code" and "message"
message = [results objectForKey:@"message"]; // No UPC Code for this scan
NSLog(@"Code Above: %@", message);
```

Comment: Mind giving an explanation with that code?

Comment: Not sure what needs explaining here: the JSON object says pretty much everything. The top-level JSON object `res` is a dictionary. It contains a dictionary with key "error" and something with key "data" (probably a string). So `results` is a dictionary containing an NSNumber "code" and a string "message". Hence when you query `[results objectForKey:@"message"]` the result is an NSString.